# Not able to Create a JSF Project in new Eclipse Indigo M6a Java EE using JBOSS Tools 3.3.o M1

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, richfaces

I have followed the below link to install and configure JBOSS Tools in Eclipse Indigo to work on a JSF project

http://planet.jboss.org/post/jboss_tools_milestone_for_eclipse_3_7_m6_indigo

Steps i followed.

1.Installed Eclipse
2.Configured Proxy
3.Loaded the Urls as specified in above link

however many of the packages fails during installation and i cant see a JSF project in the new project list.

What could be wrong here?. Please help me with some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading an outdated tutorial. Eclipse Indigo was already finalized a few weeks after that tutorial was written. Even more, it's already in SR1 stage. You can download it [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr1). Finally, you can try to install the JBoss tools through the following URL:

> http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/indigo/

It works at least for me.

Please note that you do not necessarily *need* JBoss Tools in order to be able to create a JSF project. It's already built in Eclipse for Java EE. Just create a new *Dynamic Web Project*. JSF is available as one of the project facets which is configureable in the *Configuration* option of the 1st step of the *Dynamic Web Project* wizard.

[image]

The JBoss Tools is just an additional plugin which eases JSF development with several additional (autocomplete) wizards.

#### See also:

- [JSF 2.0 tutorial with Eclipse and Glassfish](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html) - contains a lot of helpful screenshots

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply.I am now trying to install it as per tutorial.I need to add richfaces along with JSF ie why i was specifically looking for JBOSS tools plugins.

Comment: Adding RichFaces is a matter of adding 7 JAR files to `/WEB-INF/lib` of the project. Really, it's no rocket science after all. The JBoss Tools doesn't take care of this. It only adds extra wizards and autocomplete fanciness, so that you waste less time in writing and investigating JSF code. Nothing more.